The difference between sound and voice
I am confused about the noun meaning between "sound" and "voice because I want to express the meaning "i like your sound/your voice/the sound of your voice."
I search the meaning of both from the Cambridge Dictionary.

sound: something that you can hear or that can be heard
voice: the sounds that are made when people speak or sing

In my opinion, the meaning of sound contains the meaning of voice.
but I counldn't find "voice" from the Synonyms of sound,and voice too
so i am thinking if the meaning between both are quite different.
If i want to express the meaning of "i like your sound/your voice/the sound of your voice." which prhase should i use？

When people speak or sing is the important part! Only a person has a voice, but anything you can hear is a sound.

As per the dictionary, "sound" can mean anything that you can hear, including voices, music, noise, and lots of natural or artificial sounds.
"Voice" is the sound of someone speaking, but it has lots of extended meanings, such as "an expressed opinion" or "a particular style of writing".
If you say "I like your voice" you mean "the sound that you make when speaking" and perhaps also "the ideas that you express when speaking".

I might add that "the sound of your voice" makes it clear that you are talking about the sound specifically rather than the meaning of their speech. Though, I think this would be clear from context in most situations.
Also, I'd add that "I like your sound" indicates to me that you are specifically referring to some sound that is not their voice. You might say "I like your sound" to a musician if you like the way their instrument sounds, and you aren't referring to any specific aspect of the music like the lyrics or the melody.

Organs, in particular have many voices, including vox humana, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vox_humana, meant to sound like a human voice, and the direction "cantabile", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantabile, is to play sounding as a human voice.
